# How to exclude backpack-devtools from composer while installing unit tests in -dev version?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-backpack

Laravel Backpack recommends to install the backpack-devtools via composer, and to exclude them from production by running the `composer install` command with the `--no-dev` parameter. This would allow to use the package in the local environment while excluding it from production (https://backpackforlaravel.com/products/devtools).

This works perfectly fine by itself, just when I use a CI, I would run unit tests, and I would not really want to install the backpack-devtools in the temporary CI environment. Yes; one could just add that license key to the secure variables, run the `composer install` without `--no-dev` parameter and either ignore the backpack-devtools package or delete it, but I wonder if there is a smarter way of doing it and not include it at all.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way in Composer to install everything but one dependency. So no, I’m afraid you cannot do that.

What you might be able to do, however, is to run “composer remove —dev backpack/devtools” in your CI/CD pipeline, before the “composer install”. That should make it install without it.

Comment: `composer remove` might be an option. Why did someone downvote it?